# Few exchangable forms in WPF - possible?

Tags: wpf

I have few basic views in my WPF app, but I don't want to design in visual way one of them and other programmatically.

What's the best approach way to design few forms and programmatically only exchange them within the main window?

EDIT: of course, I don't want to close/open new windows ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I have a `ShellViewModel` containing the `CurrentViewModel`, and display the CurrentViewModel as a `ContentControl` the ShellView. Then to switch pages, all you do is change the `CurrentViewModel` property in the `ShellViewModel`

ShellView:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

ShellViewModel:

```
private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
{
    get { return _currentViewModel; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentViewModel != value)
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```

You can see an example of it [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)

Comment: but will I be able to design every "page" visually?